# ASP.NET 4.3 Scaffolding: Add Controller vs Add View - different behavior?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, foreign-key-relationship, scaffolding, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to dig into ASP.NET MVC 3, using the standard tutorials in the web, and I encounter a strage problem.

Currently, I am following the samples in a book, using a "Movie" class with movie genres stored in a separate entity, connected with a foreign key (okay, I am from Germany, so my class is named in German). I show only the relevant properties here. It's a database first approach using DbContext, my model was created from the edmx by using the EF 4.x DbContext Generator and the edmx was automatically created from the data base.

```
public partial class Film
{
    public Film() { }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Titel { get; set; }
    public int GenreID { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
}

public partial class Genre
{
    public Genre() { }
    public int GenreID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I create a new Controller with CRUD Views for the Film class, using a DBContext that provides a DBSet, I get an Edit view that uses a DropdownList to edit GenreID, labelled "Genre". Fine. That's what I want.

But then, I tried to create another edit view, separately. So I right-clicked into my Edit Action-Method, selected "Add View", called it "Edit2", used Film as model and "Edit" as scaffold template. In this view, I got a simple "EditorFor(m->m.GenreID)", labelled GenreID. That's not what I want.

Of course, I can change that manually. Of course, I can download a slew of scaffolding tools that claim to do better.

But I want to understand if this is a bug in the EF templates, or if my model is built wrong so that Genre / GenreID gets confused. When I create everything at once, scaffolding creates a DropDown, so there must be "just" some detail that's missing.

Comment: I'm having this same problem.  I thought it was an issue with the T4 templates, but I think it has something to do with the data passed between the wizard and the T4 template (A.K.A. `Host`)

Comment: @Brian & Rolf, did you guys figure this out? I'm having similar issues. I copied the code templates locally to modify them and for some reason it doesn't seem to pick up any foreign key relations any more.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I abandoned the topic a year ago. Other work became more important.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call your Action in your controller "Edit2".